# Today Samba just stopped working

Tags: linux, samba, samba4

So Samba4 has worked for the past 5 months with my current setup; however, today  I attempted to connect to my share and I received this error:

> \\{server} is not accessible.  You
>   might not have permission to use this
>   network resource.  Contact the
>   administrator of this server to find
>   out if you have access permissions.
>
> The specified domain either does not
>   exist or could not be contacted.

Here is my [smb.conf](http://pastebin.com/MFsYUY2y).

I have already tried restarting samba and restarting the server.  I also found an error in the log.smbd.  Which simply said that the port was already being used so smbd couldn't be started, I think that is b/c an instance of smbd is already running, which should be a problem.

Comment: Do you have log file entries for this connection attempt?

Comment: If you stop samba, and you run ps, do any samba services still run?

Comment: I have since decided to just reinstall according to the samba wiki, because it came to my attention that I installed it improperly.  Probably not the reason it no longer works, but hopefully it will fix itself when I reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be in how the samba services are started on your server. Pay close attention to any Samba README's or tutorials that are specific to your distro.

Comment: Yah the problem ended up being that I was running samba 3.5.6 as well as samba 4.  I didn't realize that Samba 4 is in alpha, and it got installed for some reason.

Comment: Ouch. You need to keep better notes/documentation about what is running where, and what revision it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might try seeing what is bound to those ports using the venerable `lsof` command:

> lsof -i :445
>
> lsof -i :137
>
> lsof -i :138
>
> lsof -i :139